# How do you use the [attribute=value] selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, css-selectors

```
var prev = b - 1;

var previousImage = $('.header ul.active').find($('li[rel=prev]'));
```

The 1st variable is an integer being deducted by 1.

The next variable named `previousImage` is what i'm having trouble with. Each one of the `li`s within the `previousImage` has a rel tag. Each increasing by 1. I just want to select that `li` with a rel tag of the number (in this case a variable).

Can someone please explain to me exactly how to use the [rel=ATTRIBUTE] selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var previousImage = $('.header ul.active').find($('li[rel="' + prev + '"]'));
```

Note that The [attribute=value] selector requires the value Part to Be wrapped in double quotes like so:

```
[attribute="value"]
```

Comment: perfect answer, worked fine. I got confused because when you assign a rel attribute, you do it like this, .attr('rel',ATTRIBUTE); That kind of threw me a bit. But yes, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

don't use another jquery object, you can do all of what you want in one easy call.

```
var previousImage = $('.header ul.active li[rel=' + rel + ']');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousImage = $('.header ul.active').find($('li[rel="'+prev+'"]'));
```

You used the string `prev` instead of the variable.

Also quotes are mandatory in an equals selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.next()` this will help u i guess http://api.jquery.com/next/
U will just use `$('li').next()` thats all